# Inaccurate values returning from Emulator Control of Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

```
            //Show the current coordinates (Convert to String and round off - 6 decimal places)
        String printLat = new DecimalFormat("0.######").format((double)currentLat);
        String printLon = new DecimalFormat("0.######").format((double)currentLon);

        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Current Location:");
        alert.setMessage("Latitude: " + printLat+ "\n" + "Longitude: " + printLon);
        alert.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {               
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Alert Dialog won't work without a listener
                //Do nothing (This will simply close your alert dialog)
            }
        });     
        alert.show();
```

Here's a part of my main class.

I should obtain what I am sending from my emulator. But instead of retrieving exact values, I'm getting this:

Latitude - 14.069315
Longitude - 121.323738

but I sent this (from my Emulator Control)
Latitude - 14.069316
Longitude - 121.323739

It's just a matter of one decimal number, and a small value, but I'm worried if this will take a big effect of what will appear on my application, because I will use these values to add markers on my Google Maps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: DecimalFormat uses half rounding, so this is just a rounding side-effect because the next digit after 5 and 8 is probably <= 5. Did you test the exact same code with the same input numbers on an actual device and got different results?

Comment: @NobuGames- i dont get what you mean, sir.
by the way, how can i round off double variables to output exact values, with 0.######?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like rounding error to me.

I wouldn't worry about this amount of error, as the [number at the sixth decimal place equates to less than 1 meter on the ground (depending what latitude the location is at)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees).